# How to refresh the last location every second?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

Pretty new in Kotlin and I am trying to setup a map marker that follows the user ever they go, which means the location need to be updated like every second. I have used FusedLocationProviderClient but it only gives the latest location once and never refresh again.

Here's the code:

```js
private fun setUpMap() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getActivity()!!,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getActivity()!!,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        map?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(getActivity()!!) { location ->
            if (location != null) {
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLatLong = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                map?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                
                //placing the current location to the map marker
                placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLong)
                map?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLong, 16f))
            } else {
            
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to use interval function manually every 5 second but I know it is not a proper way, here is the code by using interval:

```js
private fun setUpMap() {
        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 5000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getActivity()!!,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getActivity()!!,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
                map?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(getActivity()!!) { location ->
                    if (location != null) {
                        lastLocation = location
                        val currentLatLong = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                        map?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                        
                        //map marker
                        placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLong)
                        map?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLong, 16f))
                        
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
            }
        }
        timer.start()
    }
```

What is the proper way to get last location updated by using google map function? Is locationCallBack the right approach for this? Thanks.

Comment: If you want a stream of locations, use requestLocationUpdates.  It will send you updates as they're available.  Everythign you're trying to do with the timer is built in

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks, how about locationCallBack? Will it give updated location lat and long every second?